# Remote switching in rural village

Tags: relay, switching, remote, 24v

How might we control a 2" valve >2000ft away in a remote village.  We're thinking that we power the system with a 12 v or 24 v solar powered/ battery backup.  The spot in the village with line of sight to the proposed location of the array is 2000 ft.  The valve is another 230 ft beyond the array and not visible from the village.  The valve will divert monsoon contaminated water from the solar powered system that brings water to the village from 900 ft below.  Since the valve will block the flow from the seep/ spring entering the system, there is space for the diverted stream to runoff.

Comment: How big is the pipe? Have you selected a valve yet? If so, what are its specifications?

Comment: This question reminded me of this story http://www.sigcon.com/Pubs/edn/WaterHammer.htm

Comment: Are the points in sight? You could use wifi network, or so you have a GSM/GPRS network in that area? You can control over GSM/GPRS network, but you need to pay fees. Alternatively you can use VHF radio if your country gives you the frequency clear for at least one channel.

Comment: 2" piping is being used in the supply lines and between roughing filter tanks.  Haven't finalized specific valve selection.  Blocking the stream/ seep shouldn't present any water hammer.  Only intermittent electrical supply to the village, no wi-fi to depend on.  We'll be checking VHF rules, but know little about this approach.

Comment: Something like a little ISM band unlicensed telemetry should work fine, since you have line of sight. Example: http://www.microhardcorp.com/n2420.php

Comment: Er, telemetry modem.

Answer (score 1):

Is this system going to be automated or will the valve always be operated by a person?

If it requires manual input then you may find this product useful..

[1km transmitter receiver](http://www.rfsolutions.co.uk/acatalog/1000m-Low-Voltage-ELITE_XS4L.html)

This Rx can be run on 12Vdc or 24Vdc and has 4 switched outputs. Depending on the power demands of your valve you may need an external relay.